# WearableListView.Item missing from wearable support library 1.1

Tags: android, wear-os

My wear app uses WearableListView.Item for a ListView, and it worked fine and compiled - but then I upgraded Android Studio, Gradle plugin, SDK tools etc etc, and now it won't compile.

My wear build.gradle contains:

```
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
...
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 20
...

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.+'
}
```

Now it says: Error:(141, 84) error: cannot find symbol class Item

Any help out there please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the API has changed. It now depend on `RecyclerView`

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/PomepuyN/c30760eaee1e58fdd8fa) showing how to implement a `WearableListView`.

Comment: This looks interesting - where did you get this from?

Comment: I just found out how to do it by myself.

Comment: I tried this out, and you are indeed right about the interface change. Accepting. The animations don't work very well in your example however esp when scrolling fast. I suggest not animating at all and just set scale (1 to 1.5) and alpha. Can you paste the relevant changes to the interface in your answer?

Comment: The example's animations are just here to illustrate what you can do. In fact, this is the implementation of one of my app but can be easily changed / improved.I will add a comment on these lines to specify that.
I saw many complaints these days about that. And as I was working on this part, I wanted to help people.

Comment: Good job! BTW I thought I recognised you - congrats on Wear Mini Launcher! I use it myself!

Comment: In your code you should check the boolean parameter "animate" even if I didn't find documentation about it, the crazy Google release!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good implementation of WearableListView using v1.1.0 of the wearable support library that still supports the proper zooming behavior (directly from the official Google samples):

[android-WatchFace/DigitalWatchFaceWearableConfigActivity.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/watchface/DigitalWatchFaceWearableConfigActivity.java#L249)

Comment: I didn't realized this part of the sample had exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ([source](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2p0pan/psa_latest_wearable_support_library_11_does_not/)) that to workaround this you need to change:

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0'
```

This looks to only be a temporary workaround before a proper fix comes along.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you should do something like that:

```
public class ItemView extends FrameLayout implements WearableListView.OnCenterProximityListener
```

Or:

```
public class ItemView extends FrameLayout implements WearableListView.OnScrollListener
```

Because the interface WearableListView.Item doesn't apply more.
I hope to help you.